# Change TextView value on Activity creation

Tags: android

I want to change a TextViews value when my activity is created.

On the LoginActivity, I start my activity using:

```
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
```

But I dont know where to place the code for changing my textviews value.

When I place it in onCreate, my app just crashes...

my logcat is not working so I cant see my exceptions...

But it crashes when doing

```
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zanuka_username);
    t.setText("lllll");
```

onCreate

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zanuka_username);
        t.setText("lllll");

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       /** FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        **/

        //ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.zanuka_profilepicture);
        //new ImageLoadTask("http://chat.keecode.net/account/picture/1", profilePicture).execute();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to work on TextViews in MainActivity? In case please post MainActivity code is creating problems to you, so that it's easier to explain what's wrong and how to fix.

Comment: Your **t** object is null, in other words, make sure you have a TextView with id = zanuka_username declared in activity_main.xml

Comment: @Melquiades Well, I want to edit the navigation drawer... where to put this change then ?

Comment: What do you mean? You're setting content as setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), so findViewById(R.id.zanuka_username) will look for a TextView with id="zanuka_username" in activity_main.xml (or other layout files if you used "include"); in other words, put it in activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

which tells you that your TextView t is NULL. The reason of this is a missing TextView with id="zanuka_username" in your activity_main.xml.

Comment: Well, where to edit the navigation drawer ? It does not have an own class but I can edit it on an event in the main activity, but not in the onCreate method.. Where to do it then ?

Comment: Where's your zanuka_username TextView then? Not knowing your layout structure, it's a guess work, but have a look at how it's structured with a default Navigation Drawer layout project (just create one with Android Studio). You will see that the layout for drawer is in nav_header_main.xml and activity_main_drawer.xml (in menu folder) (used AS 2.0 Beta2)

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView mTextView;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
        mTextView.setText("Main activity created");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post your MainActivity oncreate code and exception you are getting

This should work

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("Hello World");
```

in your onCreate.

Comment: Well, my logcat does not work... I cant see my exceptions but I'll try with logcat on my phone

Comment: Ok I managed it to get it to work:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please post your complete fatal exception logs and activity_main.xml layout file contents

Comment: There is no tex tview with id zanuka_username in your activity_main.xml. That's is why you are getting null pointer exception. You need to have elements in layout you are inflating.