# How to display contents of array in several TextViews?

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I am trying to work out how to display the contents of the below array recipeDetail into the following TextViews. I already have an adapter for the recyclerview just trying to work out how to populate the other TextViews. I can provide the other code if required eg. full class code or recyclerView adapter.

**XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recipe" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Meal Plan" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shopping List" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/recipeImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recipeImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipeName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/courseText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/servingsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/costText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/courseText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caloriesText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/servingsText" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listIngredient"
    android:name="com.stu54259.plan2cook.Recipe"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/caloriesText"
    tools:context=".Recipe"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/methodText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listIngredient" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recipeName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recipeImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java**

```
 public void loadRecipe() {
        recipeDetail.clear();
        db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String query = "";
        String LOAD_RECIPE = " SELECT recipe_name, description, course, servings, calories, preparation_time, method, category, image, cost FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE;
        query = LOAD_RECIPE + " WHERE recipe_name LIKE ?";
        c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Recipe recipe = new com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Recipe();
                recipe.setRecipe_name(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("recipe_name")));
                recipe.setDescription(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("description")));
                recipe.setCourse(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("course")));
                recipe.setServings(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("servings")));
                recipe.setCalories(cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("calories")));
                recipe.setPreparation_time(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("preparation_time")));
                recipe.setMethod(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("method")));
                recipe.setCategory(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("category")));
                recipe.setImage(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("image")));
                recipe.setCost(cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("cost")));
                recipeDetail.add(recipe);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            cur.close();
        }

    }
```

**Update**

```
package com.stu54259.plan2cook;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.RecipeList;
import com.stu54259.plan2cook.database.DatabaseManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.stu54259.plan2cook.database.DatabaseManager.*;

public class Recipe extends MainActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ImageView recipeImage;
    TextView recipeName, descriptionText, courseText, servingsText, costText, caloriesText, methodText;
    RecyclerView listIngredient;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String search_name;
    Cursor c, cur;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapterRecipe;
    List<RecipeList> itemRecipe = new ArrayList<>();
    List<com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Recipe> recipeDetail = new ArrayList<>();


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);
        //search_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
        search_name = "Speedy chicken couscous";

        loadIngredient();
        //recyclerview Recipe
        adapterRecipe = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, itemRecipe);
        listIngredient = findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        listIngredient.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        listIngredient.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        listIngredient.setAdapter(adapterRecipe);
        loadRecipe();
        // Code not completed, just thought something like this might work
        recipeName = findViewById(R.id.recipeName);
        recipeName.setText(getRecipe_name());
    }
    public void loadIngredient() {
        itemRecipe.clear();
        db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String RECIPE_SEARCH = " SELECT A.recipe, A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
                "FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY + " AS A JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_INGREDIENTS +
                " AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name";
        String selectQuery = "";
        selectQuery = RECIPE_SEARCH + " WHERE A.recipe LIKE ?";
        c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RecipeList recipeList = new RecipeList();
                recipeList.setRecipe(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("recipe")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_amount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_quantity")));
                recipeList.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("measurement_name")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name")));
                recipeList.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description")));
                itemRecipe.add(recipeList);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

    }
    public void loadRecipe() {
        recipeDetail.clear();
        db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String query = "";
        String LOAD_RECIPE = " SELECT recipe_name, description, course, servings, calories, preparation_time, method, category, image, cost FROM " + TABLE_RECIPE;
        query = LOAD_RECIPE + " WHERE recipe_name LIKE ?";
        c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Recipe recipe = new com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Recipe();
                recipe.setRecipe_name(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("recipe_name")));
                recipe.setDescription(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("description")));
                recipe.setCourse(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("course")));
                recipe.setServings(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("servings")));
                recipe.setCalories(cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("calories")));
                recipe.setPreparation_time(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("preparation_time")));
                recipe.setMethod(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("method")));
                recipe.setCategory(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("category")));
                recipe.setImage(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("image")));
                recipe.setCost(cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("cost")));
                recipeDetail.add(recipe);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            cur.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please be a little more clear about what you are trying to do and what have you tried so far to achieve that. Also please mention at what specific point you are facing issues.

Comment: try this approach and populate all text views
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35246757/13069716

Comment: I thought something like this might of worked but i'm clearly mistaken. recipeName = findViewById(R.id.recipeName);
        recipeName.setText(getRecipe_name());

Comment: Provide the full Activity/Fragment code and how you are doing the above operation that's not working for you

Comment: I've attached further code. What I need help with is how to retrieve the individual Strings from the recipeDetail arraylist and put them in their relevant TextView?